# Programmatically Split A Post Into Multiple Pages

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, navigation, split

We all know that when you're creating a standard post in WordPress you can split the post into multiple pages by adding this code into the text body:

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

Is it possible to split a post up like this programatically? I have a gallery custom post type which only displays attached images, so it's not possible to add the above comment anywhere. I would like the gallery to display *n* images at a time and then show pagination links. (I'll in fact be using an infinite scroll script but that's irrelevant).

Comment: How does your gallery post type work? How does it create galleries?

Comment: It is a CPT which supports 'Title' and 'Thumbnail'. The images are added to the gallery using the Attachments plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/attachments/) so there is essentially no content.

Comment: Still not clear how these components interact. Is this question dependent on how that plugin works?

Comment: No, the plugin is irrelevant to be honest. I was wondering if it was possible to trigger whatever happens when the `<!--nextpage-->` tag is added programatically so that I can use the `/cpt/post-name/page/1` URL's without having to custom code something.